# Is this a bug in Kotlin or I missing something?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin

I don't have to much experience in multi-threading. So not sure if I got right the following Java code decompiled from Kotlin.

Here is the Kotlin code:

```
companion object {
    @Volatile private var INSTANCE: SomeDatabase? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context): SomeDatabase =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: buildDatabase(context).also { INSTANCE = it }
            }
}
```

Here is the decompiled code in Java:

```
     SomeDatabase var10000 = ((SomeDatabase.Companion)this).getINSTANCE();
     if (var10000 == null) {
        synchronized(this){}

        SomeDatabase var4;
        try {
           var10000 = SomeDatabase.Companion.getINSTANCE();
           if (var10000 == null) {

               ...

        var10000 = var4;
     }

     return var10000;
```

Doesn't this mean that code is actually not synchronized because of empty block in `synchronized(this){}`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at the bytecode itself without decompiling it, you'll see that the synchronization happens as it should - this here is a version stripped of lots of load and store operations, line numbers, etc., but what matters is where the `MONITORENTER` and `MONITOREXIT` instructions are:

```
public final getInstance(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/example/SomeDatabase;
    LDC "context"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    INVOKESTATIC com/example/Foo.access$getINSTANCE$cp ()Lcom/example/SomeDatabase;
    MONITORENTER
    INVOKESTATIC com/example/Foo.access$getINSTANCE$cp ()Lcom/example/SomeDatabase;
    INVOKESTATIC com/example/FooKt.buildDatabase (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/example/SomeDatabase;
    INVOKESTATIC com/example/Foo.access$setINSTANCE$cp (Lcom/example/SomeDatabase;)V
    MONITOREXIT
    MONITOREXIT
    ARETURN
```

The issue you're seeing is not a bug in the compiler, but rather an issue with the decompiler, which isn't particularly rare. It's quite the challenge to decompile arbitrary generated bytecode back to Java.

Comment: You've got `MONITOREXIT` twice. Is that by accident?

Comment: It was in the bytecode twice - I don't remember it exactly right now and don't have the project in front of me, but I believe it was for the two different return branches of the Elvis operator.

Comment: Ah, OK. So between them there must have been `ARETURN`, `GOTO` or something else.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that was the case, I just stripped out many many instructions to focus on these ones.